# How to access the children of an XML response - Google Apps Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I am building a function that should take the elements of an XML response and store each iteration of an element in it's own row in a spreadsheet until all the elements have been accounted for. Please see my code below, I am able to print the element header and value to the logger, but not access each value for transfer to a sheet. Please advise.

```
function testPOST(e) {

var url = "API_URL";

var payload = e;

var options =
    {
      "method"  : "POST",
      "payload" : payload,   
      "followRedirects" : true,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  //    Logger.log(result);
  Logger.log(result.getResponseCode() + "\n\n");
}

/*TESTING*/
var od = XmlService.parse(result);
pm = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(od);
Logger.log(pm);

/* Preferred Approach */  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Output"),
    temps = [],
    root = XmlService.parse(result).getRootElement().getDescendants(),
    temps = root;
for (var [key,val] in temps)
{
  if(val == "")
  {
    continue;
  }
  else{
    //      Logger.log("Index Value:"+e.values[key]+"\n");
    Logger.log(key+" Value:"+val+ "\n");  
  }
}
}
```

Here is an example of the logger output.

```
[19-07-17 17:05:39:717 EDT] 200


[19-07-17 17:05:39:838 EDT] 0 Value:[Element: <serv:header [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:839 EDT] 1 Value:[Element: <serv:response [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:840 EDT] 2 Value:[Element: <serv:result [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:840 EDT] 3 Value:SUCCESS

[19-07-17 17:05:39:840 EDT] 4 Value:[Element: <serv:gsbStatus [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:841 EDT] 5 Value:BACKUP

[19-07-17 17:05:39:841 EDT] 6 Value:[Element: <serv:body [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:842 EDT] 7 Value:[Element: <serv:bodyContent [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:842 EDT] 8 Value:[Element: <use:user [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:842 EDT] 9 Value:[Element: <use:userID [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:843 EDT] 10 Value:UID

[19-07-17 17:05:39:843 EDT] 11 Value:[Element: <use:Id [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:844 EDT] 12 Value:ID

[19-07-17 17:05:39:844 EDT] 13 Value:[Element: <use:firstName [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:844 EDT] 14 Value:NAME

[19-07-17 17:05:39:845 EDT] 15 Value:[Element: <use:lastName [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:845 EDT] 16 Value:NAME

[19-07-17 17:05:39:846 EDT] 17 Value:[Element: <use:email [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:846 EDT] 18 Value:EMAIL

[19-07-17 17:05:39:846 EDT] 19 Value:[Element: <use:userRoleType [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:847 EDT] 20 Value:HOST

[19-07-17 17:05:39:848 EDT] 21 Value:[Element: <use:registrationDate [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:848 EDT] 22 Value:DATE

[19-07-17 17:05:39:849 EDT] 23 Value:[Element: <use:active [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:849 EDT] 24 Value:ACTIVATED

[19-07-17 17:05:39:850 EDT] 25 Value:[Element: <use:timeZoneID [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:850 EDT] 26 Value:11

[19-07-17 17:05:39:851 EDT] 27 Value:[Element: <use:lastLoginTime [Namespace: URL]/>]

**Iterates**

[19-07-17 17:05:39:852 EDT] 28 Value:DATE

[19-07-17 17:05:39:842 EDT] 8 Value:[Element: <use:user [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:842 EDT] 9 Value:[Element: <use:userID [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:843 EDT] 10 Value:UID

[19-07-17 17:05:39:843 EDT] 11 Value:[Element: <use:Id [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:844 EDT] 12 Value:ID

[19-07-17 17:05:39:844 EDT] 13 Value:[Element: <use:firstName [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:844 EDT] 14 Value:NAME

[19-07-17 17:05:39:845 EDT] 15 Value:[Element: <use:lastName [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:845 EDT] 16 Value:NAME

[19-07-17 17:05:39:846 EDT] 17 Value:[Element: <use:email [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:846 EDT] 18 Value:EMAIL

[19-07-17 17:05:39:846 EDT] 19 Value:[Element: <use:userRoleType [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:847 EDT] 20 Value:HOST

[19-07-17 17:05:39:848 EDT] 21 Value:[Element: <use:registrationDate [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:848 EDT] 22 Value:DATE

[19-07-17 17:05:39:849 EDT] 23 Value:[Element: <use:active [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:849 EDT] 24 Value:ACTIVATED

[19-07-17 17:05:39:850 EDT] 25 Value:[Element: <use:timeZoneID [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:850 EDT] 26 Value:11

[19-07-17 17:05:39:851 EDT] 27 Value:[Element: <use:lastLoginTime [Namespace: URL]/>]

[19-07-17 17:05:39:852 EDT] 28 Value:DATE
```

**Value of URLFetchApp.fetch**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service" xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common" xmlns:use="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user">
  <serv:header>
    <serv:response>
      <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
      <serv:gsbStatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbStatus>
    </serv:response>
  </serv:header>
  <serv:body>
    <serv:bodyContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="use:lstsummaryUserResponse">
      <use:user>
        <use:userID>UID</use:userID>
        <use:webExId>ID</use:webExId>
        <use:firstName>NAME</use:firstName>
        <use:lastName>NAME</use:lastName>
        <use:email>EMAIL</use:email>
        <use:userRoleType>HOST</use:userRoleType>
        <use:registrationDate>DATE</use:registrationDate>
        <use:active>ACTIVATED</use:active>
        <use:timeZoneID>11</use:timeZoneID>
        <use:lastLoginTime>DATE</use:lastLoginTime>
      </use:user>
      <use:user>
        <use:userID>UID</use:userID>
        <use:webExId>ID</use:webExId>
        <use:firstName>NAME</use:firstName>
        <use:lastName>NAME</use:lastName>
        <use:email>EMAIL</use:email>
        <use:userRoleType>SITEADMIN</use:userRoleType>
        <use:registrationDate>DATE</use:registrationDate>
        <use:active>ACTIVATED</use:active>
        <use:timeZoneID>7</use:timeZoneID>
        <use:lastLoginTime>DATE</use:lastLoginTime>
      </use:user>
      <use:matchingRecords>
                <serv:total>2</serv:total>
                <serv:returned>2</serv:returned>
                <serv:startFrom>1</serv:startFrom>
            </use:matchingRecords>
        </serv:bodyContent>
    </serv:body>
</serv:message>
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the value of `result` of `var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)` and the result you want? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Take a look at the [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) of the class. There it shows how to access the children of the XML file.

Comment: Jescanellas I have attempted this as the preferred approached however getChildren() returns null?

@Tanaike I will edit the question to show the value of fetch

Comment: Thank you for replying. By your sample XML data, I proposed a sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your correspondence. This issue occurs when there are more than 500 user accounts on a given site (the XML call can return up to 500) and I'm informed can be paginated but using the startFrom value and iterating until no results are returned however I am unable to return results from the initial call due to the following Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 12 but the range has 11. (referencing getRange())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to put the values to Spreadsheet by parsing the XML data.
- In your sample XML data, the header and values for putting to Spreadsheet are as follows.

  - Header: `userID   webExId firstName   lastName    email   userRoleType    registrationDate    active  timeZoneID  lastLoginTime`
  - Values:

    - `UID  ID  NAME    NAME    EMAIL   HOST    DATE    ACTIVATED   11  DATE`
    - `UID  ID  NAME    NAME    EMAIL   SITEADMIN   DATE    ACTIVATED   7   DATE`

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the Spreadsheet ID.

```
function myFunction() {
  var id = "###"; // <--- Please set the Spreadsheet ID here.

  // This is the sample XML data from your updated question.
  var result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service" xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common" xmlns:use="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user"><serv:header><serv:response><serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result><serv:gsbStatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbStatus></serv:response></serv:header><serv:body><serv:bodyContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="use:lstsummaryUserResponse"><use:user><use:userID>UID</use:userID><use:webExId>ID</use:webExId><use:firstName>NAME</use:firstName><use:lastName>NAME</use:lastName><use:email>EMAIL</use:email><use:userRoleType>HOST</use:userRoleType><use:registrationDate>DATE</use:registrationDate><use:active>ACTIVATED</use:active><use:timeZoneID>11</use:timeZoneID><use:lastLoginTime>DATE</use:lastLoginTime></use:user><use:user><use:userID>UID</use:userID><use:webExId>ID</use:webExId><use:firstName>NAME</use:firstName><use:lastName>NAME</use:lastName><use:email>EMAIL</use:email><use:userRoleType>SITEADMIN</use:userRoleType><use:registrationDate>DATE</use:registrationDate><use:active>ACTIVATED</use:active><use:timeZoneID>7</use:timeZoneID><use:lastLoginTime>DATE</use:lastLoginTime></use:user><use:matchingRecords><serv:total>2</serv:total><serv:returned>2</serv:returned><serv:startFrom>1</serv:startFrom></use:matchingRecords></serv:bodyContent></serv:body></serv:message>';

  var header = [];
  var values = [];
  var root = XmlService.parse(result).getRootElement();
  var c1 = root.getChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
    if (c1[i].getName() == "body") {
      var c2 = c1[i].getChildren()[0].getChildren();
      for (var j = 0; j < c2.length; j++) {
        if (c2[j].getName() == "user") {
          var c3 = c2[j].getChildren();
          var temp = [];
          for (var k = 0; k < c3.length; k++) {
            if (j == 0) header.push(c3[k].getName());
            temp.push(c3[k].getValue());
          }
          values.push(temp);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  values.unshift(header);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Output");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your sample XML data, the order of each element is the same. This script uses this. If the order is random, at first, it is required to be declare the header.

#### References:

- [Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)
- [getChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getchildren)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and assistance. This worked wonderfully!

Comment: I am receiving an error "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 11 but the range has 10."

Could this be for the _matchingRecords_ Element?

Each call can only return 500 records and then the startfrom element needs to increment until no records are returned. Would you be able to assist?

Comment: @Mikal D Chavez Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. I can confirm that when I use your provided sample XML data, no error occurs. If you use the different data from the sample XML data you provided, I cannot understand about it. If it's so, can you post it as new question by including the information for replicating your issue? I would like to confirm about it and correctly understand it. Can you do it? If I misunderstood your replying, please tell me.

Comment: Thank you for your correspondence. This issue occurs when there are more than 500 user accounts on a given site (the XML call can return up to 500) and I'm informed can be paginated but using the startFrom value and iterating until no results are returned however I am unable to return results from the initial call due to the following Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 12 but the range has 11. (referencing getRange())

Comment: @Mikal D Chavez Thank you for your response. I apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, in my environment, I cannot replicate your situation from your replying. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm it. And also it will also help other users think of your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked this at the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106515/columns-in-the-data-does-not-match-the-number-of-columns-in-the-range-the-data

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I saw it, I noticed that an answer has already posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.